# Accessing errors in formControName with the help of ngFor index

Tags: angular

I want to apply apply 'voucher-table-entry-error' class on input if FormControlName of that Input have error.
But when i try to access FormControlGroup using ngFor's Index 'i'
I am getting error
'No overload match this call'

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
<tbody>
    <div [formGroup]="voucherEntries" class="voucher-entries-container">
        <!-- Create Rows -->
        <tr formArrayName='entries' *ngFor="let control of entriesControls.controls; let i = index"
            class="table-data">
            <td [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let header of headers; let headerIndex = index" [style.flex]="header.flex">
                <div 
                    [id]="headerIndex+1"
                    [tabIndex]="header.skip" 
                    [style.flex]="header.flex"
                    (keydown)="test($event)"
                    >
                    <input 
                        ***Here 'i' is giving error***
                        [ngClass]="{'voucher-table-entry-error': this.voucherEntries.get('entries')?.get(i)?.get('name')?.errors}"
                        tabindex="1"
                        [id]="i" 
                        list="nameEntryList"
                        [placeholder]="header.header" 
                        [formControlName]="header.header"
                        (keyup)="[autoGenNextEntryRows($event)]"
                        (keydown.escape)='removeFocus($event)'
                        type="text">
                  
                    <datalist id="nameEntryList">
                        <option *ngFor="let item of itemData;" [value]="item.desc.name"></option>
                    </datalist>
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </div>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to replace `.get(i)` with `.get(i.toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<tr formArrayName='entries' *ngFor="let control of entriesControls.controls">
  <td [formGroup]="control" *ngFor="let header of headers" [style.flex]="header.flex">
    <!-- ... -->
      [ngClass]="{'voucher-table-entry-error': control.get('name').invalid"
```

Use the form group directly instead of the index, it reduces your syntax and looks clearer.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can not use the "variable" of the loop to use as formGroup. Angular only know about this variable is an AbstractControl. NOTE: In this [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30264#issuecomment-1598502912) in github I create a directive to iterate over a FormArray

Comment: Yes you can, either by casting it to any in your HTML (`$any(control)`), or by creating a getter that type the controls as an array of form controls/groups

Comment: (Hence your directive being a little bit oberkill TBH)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "get(i)"

With get you can use the "dot" notation:

```
[ngClass]="{'voucher-table-entry-error': 
             this.voucherEntries.get('entries.'+i+'.name')?.errors}"
```

NOTE: To give a class you can also use

```
[class.voucher-table-entry-error]=
       "this.voucherEntries.get('entries.'+i+'.name')?.errors}"`
```

NOTE2: really Angular add to your inputs the ng-invalid class, you can use this class instead of create a new class, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes)